# remove last id session

Tags: php, session

On my page, I have a checkbox, the user can select checbox and go after in comparison page
For that I use the session save the id checkbox selected.

The user can return on a page wehre there is again checkbox and select other.

The problem with this selections, we can have the same id products selected under a session.

ex
first action

```
id = 1
id = 2
id = 3
```

go to selected comparison page

second action

```
id = 2
id = 4
id = 5
```

third action

```
id = 2
id = 4
id = 6
```

To remove the id I use this code :

```
  $products_id = HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']);

  if (is_array($_SESSION['productsCompare']) && isset($products_id)) {
    $remove_array = $_SESSION['productsCompare'];

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($remove_array as $value) {
      if ($value == $products_id) {
        unset($_SESSION['productsCompare'][$i]);
      }

      $i++;
    }

    if (count($remove_array) == 1) {
      unset($_SESSION['productsCompare']);
    }
  }
```

like you can see, if `$value == $products_id` 
 the id s removed, but not the id duplicated.

My problem is when there is just one product with the 3 or 4 same duplicate id.
I must click on remove button 4 times to remove the products.

How to udate the loop to erase all the same id in only one time ?

Thank you.

example of `$_SESSION['productsCompare']` duplicated

```
   array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "14" [1]=> string(2) "14" [2]=> string(2) "14" [3]=> string(2) "14" [4]=> string(2) "13" [5]=> string(2) "13" [6]=> string(2) "14" [7]=> string(2) "13" [8]=> string(2) "14" [9]=> string(2) "13" [10]=> string(2) "11" }
```

Comment: what does the form look like? do you have the code for it? and you are you setting the value for $_SESSION['productsCompare'] because i dont see it.

Comment: @pauldrodriguez. See above, I added information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate values in the array, try using the `array_unique` method.

also, `$_POST['products_id']` might be returning an array of product ids.

if this is the case, then `$value == $products_id` wont work, and you will have to replace it with `in_array($value,$products_id)` instead.

Comment: No don't work because $_POST['products_id'] is  not an array but just a number id = 14 for example.